# why does Xamarin UITest restart app between tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.uitest

Why does visual studio restart my app for all testcases when running all test using a standard xamarin uitest structure?

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin UItest restarts the app (and cleans the app data by default) to ensure a clean environment for each test.

Imagine that a test fails. The test would leave the app in a state which subsequent tests might not expect. Subsequent tests would therefore fail just because that one test failed in the first place.

Disabling that behavior is not recommended, but you can do so by using

```
ConfigureApp
    .Android // .iOS respectively
    // ...
    .ConnectToApp();
```

instead of

```
ConfigureApp
    .Android // .iOS respectively
    // ...
    .StartApp();
```

Comment: Why it is working locally but not working on visual studio appcenter?

Comment: @UbaidRana did you figure this out. I'm just thinking about trying an IF DEBUG approach with `StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear)`. However, I'm guess these must all be ignored by app center. I'm appecting you'd confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
ConfigureApp
  .iOS // .Android
  .StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NUnit, try using [TestFixtureSetUp] instead of [SetUp]. This way Set Up will be executed once pro Test Fixture.

([TearDown] will help to avoid problems, in case one of the tests in fixture fails and does not return App to "Start" state)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.UITest follows the Nunit Framework. the [Setup] attributed method is called before each test where the app start code is written.

if your intention is to start the app only for one time for all test cases, you can do that in  [OneTimeSetUp] attributed method inside a class with  [SetUpFixture]

example  (NUnit3)

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class BaseTextFixture
{

    public BaseTextFixture()
    {
    }

[OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
    // this method is called only one time for all tests
    }
}
```